# Bootstrap 3.3.6 Nav Bar Item not taking full width when viewed in small resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am facing a strange issue. JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/p2d2m72z/

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">
      Website
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home-menu" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="home-menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a class="navbar-brand">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">Hello World</div>
```

When I am resizing the page for mobile device and try to toggle the collapsible navigation bar, I see that the nav items are only taking up width of the content and not the li width.

I tried to debug and could not resolve the issue. I followed W3Schools tutorial and it is working fine: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse&stacked=h

Am I missing out something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove `class="navbar-brand"` from anchor tag will make as your expected output.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">
      Website
    </a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#home-menu" aria-expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="home-menu">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a >Home</a></li>
      <li><a  href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a  href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a  href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      <li><a  href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">Hello World</div>
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2d2m72z/1/)**

Comment: Thanks ketan for ur quick response.. it solved my issue

Comment: @AshishSantikari You welcome. Don't forget to accept it as answer by clicking on right symbol.